# Solving a Simple Integral Equation

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-equations

I'm looking to solve the integral equation
$$f(x)=a\int_x^{x+b}f(t)\,dt,$$
for positive $a,b$. However, I've gotten stuck. My current approach is to apply a Laplace Transform to obtain (denoting $F=\mathscr{L}\{f\}$ as the Laplace transform of $f$)
$$F(s)=\frac{f(0)}{s}+\frac{a}{s}\left(\mathscr{L}\{f(x+b)\}-F(s)\right).$$

At this point I am unsure how to handle the Laplace transform of $f(x+b)$ since $b$ is positive. If I can express it in terms of $F$, I can solve the resulting equation for $F$ and invert the transform. Any tips on how to solve this equation would be appreciated!

As a side note, the solution has the form $f\sim e^{Bx}$ for constant $B$, so I feel that directly solving this equation should be possible.

Comment: Try to differentiate with respect to $x$ to get a differential equation.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I have tried this, but I run into a similar predicament with the function evaluated at $x+b$

Comment: Reusing variables ($x$ in this case) is confusing at best, and can easily lead to errors. You should use a different variable of integration: $f(x)=a\int_x^{x+b}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, I changed the notation as you suggested.

Comment: The solution space is a linear space. So if the solution is unique, it must be $0$.

Comment: @copper.hat the solution must satisfy $M=\int_0^Lf(x)dx$ for some $M,L>0$, so $0$ is not the unique solution It is an exponential.

Comment: @superckl Then try the [Leibniz rule for Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: @superckl I do not understand what you mean by that. The zero function does satisfy the equation. The solution space is a linear space. If there are additional constraints then you should add them to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiating, we get the equation
$$
f'(x)=a(f(x+b)-f(x))\tag1
$$
Taking the Fourier Transform, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)e^{-2\pi i\gamma x}\,\mathrm{d}x&=a\int_{-\infty}^\infty(f(x+b)-f(x))e^{-2\pi i\gamma x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
2\pi i\gamma \hat{f}(\gamma)&=a\!\left(e^{2\pi ib\gamma}-1\right)\hat{f}(\gamma)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Either $\hat{f}=0$ or $2\pi i\gamma=a\!\left(e^{2\pi ib\gamma}-1\right)$. The latter has the solutions
$$\newcommand{\W}{\operatorname{W}}
\begin{align}
2\pi i\gamma&=a\!\left(e^{2\pi ib\gamma}-1\right)\tag{3a}\\
2\pi ib\gamma&=ab\!\left(e^{2\pi ib\gamma}-1\right)\tag{3b}\\
2\pi ib\gamma+ab&=abe^{2\pi ib\gamma}\tag{3c}\\
2\pi ib\gamma+ab&=abe^{-ab}e^{2\pi ib\gamma+ab}\tag{3d}\\
2\pi ib\gamma+ab&=-\W\left(-abe^{-ab}\right)\tag{3e}\\
2\pi ib\gamma&=-ab-\W\left(-abe^{-ab}\right)\tag{3f}\\
\gamma&=\frac i{2\pi b}\left(ab+\W\left(-abe^{-ab}\right)\right)\tag{3g}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: cancelling $\hat{f}(\gamma)\ne0$ from $\text{(2b)}$
$\text{(3b)}$: multiply both sides by $b$
$\text{(3c)}$: add $ab$ to both sides
$\text{(3d)}$: multiply the right side by $e^{-ab}e^{ab}=1$
$\text{(3e)}$: multiply both sides by $-e^{-(2\pi ib\gamma+ab)}$, getting
$\phantom{\text{(3e):}}$ $-(2\pi ib\gamma+ab)e^{-(2\pi ib\gamma+ab)}=-abe^{-ab}$
$\phantom{\text{(3e):}}$ then solve for $2\pi ib\gamma+ab$ by applying $-\W$ to both sides ([Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function))
$\text{(3f)}$: subtract $ab$ from both sides
$\text{(3g)}$: divide both sides by $2\pi ib$

So $\hat{f}=0$ or $\hat{f}$ is supported at $\gamma=\frac i{2\pi b}\left(ab+\W\left(-abe^{-ab}\right)\right)$. That is,
$$
f(x)=ce^{-\frac1b\left(ab+\W\left(-abe^{-ab}\right)\right)x}\tag4
$$
If $ab\le0$ or $ab=1$, then $\W\left(-abe^{-ab}\right)=-ab$, and $(4)$ says that $f(x)=c$.

If $ab\gt0$ and $ab\ne1$, then there are two branches for $\W\left(-abe^{-ab}\right)$; one gives $f(x)=c$ and the other gives exponential growth for $0\lt ab\lt1$ and exponential decay for $ab\gt1$.

Comment: [+1] Very nice solution. Maybe it is good to say what Lambert $W$ function is (it is largely unknown)

Comment: @JeanMarie: Lambert W is becoming more well-known these days, but I had meant to add an explanation for $(3)$ anyway.

Comment: I have personally discovered it rather late... but reading your answer, I realized that the solution of the equation  in my part A) was expressible using $W$ exactly in the same way as yours ! A big thank...

Comment: @JeanMarie. It was introduced to me in 1959 as a curiosity at Bordeaux university.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I just had a look at my analysis books (in french and english) from the time of my studies : I am unable to find any reference to function W...

Comment: @JeanMarie. It was not from a book but from a "strange" professor

Comment: To apply the Fourier transform the function needs to be $L^1$ (or $L^2$)?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I found a nice [article](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf) explaining many aspects (historical aspects in particular) about W function and about Lambert.  It is said there that letter $W$ was very lately introduced for a Maple implementation.

Comment: @copper.hat: That is true. However, we can work from $(2)$ to $(1)$ and $\hat{f}$ needs to be supported at a point, so $\hat{f}$ needs to be a limit of approximations to a delta function, and those *are* in $L^1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=a\int_x^{x+b}f(t)\,dt \tag{1}$$

Two steps:

A) First of all, let us look for solutions of (1) of the form $f(x)=Ke^{Bx}$ ($K$ arbitrary constant), we get:

$$Ke^{Bx}=\frac{a}{B}[Ke^{Bt}]_{t=x}^{t=x+b}$$

$$e^{Bx}=\frac{a}{B}(e^{B(x+b)}-e^{Bx})$$

$$e^{Bx}=\frac{a}{B}(e^{Bb}-1)e^{Bx} \ \ \text{for all} \ x.$$

Otherwise said, $B$ must fulfill the following equation:

$$\frac{a}{B}(e^{Bb}-1)=1 \iff B=a(e^{Bb}-1) \iff $$

$$Bb=ab(e^{Bb}-1)\tag{*}$$

which has the solution:

$$B=- \ \frac{1}{b}(ab+W(-e^{-ab})) \tag{**}$$

where $W$ denotes Lambert function defined [here] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

(**) is obtained from (*) by using the following result about $W$ function that can be found in this article:

"The general solution of equation

$$x=\alpha+\beta e^{\gamma x} \ \ \text{is} \ \ x=\alpha - \frac{1}{\gamma}W(-\beta \gamma e^{\alpha \gamma})"$$

(take $\alpha=-ab, \beta=\gamma=1$)

**Remark:** A special case occurs when $ab=1$: indeed, as $W(-e^{-1})=-1$, (**) gives $B=0$. Therefore constant functions $f(x)=Ke^0$ can be solutions.

---

B) Now, let us transform directly equation (1) into a convolution:

$$f=a \mathbb{1}_{[-b,0]} \star f \tag{2}$$

where $\mathbb{1}_{[-b,0]}$ is the characteristic function of interval $[-b,0]$, also called "rectangular" function  on the interval.

Let us use on (2) the differentiation property of a convolution:

$$(\phi \star \psi)'=\phi' \star \psi$$

giving

$$f'= a(\delta_{-b}-\delta_0) \star f$$

(indeed, differentiation at the 'jumps' of the Rect function give Dirac $\delta$s in $-b$ and $0$).

$$f'= a(\delta_{-b} \star f-\delta_0 \star f)$$

Finally, we get the following differential-difference equation for $f$:

$$f'(x)= a(f(x+b)-f(x)) \tag{3}$$

(convolution by a Dirac = shift)

Up to you for applying Laplace Transform to (3)...

**Remarks:**

a) Take into account the constraint $f(0)=\int_0^b f(u)du$.

b) It could be interesting to briefly explain how you have obtained the Laplace Transform of the initial equation.

c) An interesting particular case in (3) is when $a=\frac{1}{b}$ giving:

$$f'(x)= \dfrac{f(x+b)-f(x)}{b} \tag{3}$$

which is verified by any affine function with equation

$$f(x)=mx+n$$

But constraint (1) gives

$$f(0)=\int_0^b f(t)dt \ \ \implies \ \ n=a(\tfrac12 mb^2+nb)$$

which (taking into account relationship $ab=1$) forces $m=0$. Therefore, only constant functions "survive" ; in this way, we find back the functions we had already considered in the remark of part A)... nothing new under the sun...

d) Equation (3) is reached in a much more direct manner in robjon's answer. The merit of my approach is to browse different useful analysis techniques.

Comment: I have attempted to improve this answer on several aspects. I am indebted to @copper.hat who has spotted an error, now fixed.